# Is it possible to serve different DocumentRoot from Virtual Host in Apache conf depending on IP of the visitor?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf, documentroot

I just wonder if it's possible to define several DocumentRoots for single VirtualHost in httpd.conf and serve them out depending on IP of the visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) including our very own [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: Actually I wondered if it's possible to place conditional directly into the VirtualHost definition.

Comment: @Jayarjo, not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: 6 years later, does `apache-2.4` make it possible with the `If` clause now?